Are there integrated philosophical models for moral agents as the cause of intentional or unintentional consequences?
How Even the Buddha Faced Delusion Before Enlightenment?
https://youtu.be/6nnHq6dLwqk?t=624

As the Buddha said there are four courses of action that may be open to us at any particular time:

one that we want to do and will give good results
one that we don't want to do and will give bad results
one that we want to do but will give bad results; and
one that we don't want to do but will give good results

The first two are no-brainers. We don't need much intelligence to do the first and avoid the second. The measure of our true intelligence lies in how we handle the last two choices.

The concept of good or bad results would depend on moral perceptions of self, others, and the distribution of benefits or harm in a social situation. The law does not prohibit all actions that might cause others to complain of harm. It only prohibits or punishes or remedies actions that cause so-called actionable harm. A person who is an ethical Buddhist would apparently curb their own liberty and act to cause mostly good to self, others, and sentient beings while making efforts to minimize harm which I think is a worthy yet unattainable psychological ideal.
The legal and political systems consider human actions, intentions, and consequences to apply the facts to the law or to perform cost benefit analysis in the context of public goods theory. In philosophy do concepts of deontology, consequentialism, and utility provide an adequate description of actions, intentions, and consequences or are there more integrated philosophical models?
